# BAM EventBus Service

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

> Execute event error.Error(s) occurred while executing events, see TDDS_FailedTrackingData table for more details.SqlServer:'server name',database:BizTalkDTADb."

How can get rid of this error? In past we are using BAM portal and we just removed BAM but some of tracing will be there to generate this type of error message ? 
[image: BAM EventBus Service]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Exceptions sendport was the culprit. It contains a pipeline component called
                  "ESB BAM Tracker” 
that was enabled by default. The solution was to disable this pipeline component:

[image: all exceptions send port]